# How to communicate same Java Application through Active-MQ Broker in Failover Scenario?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, messagebroker, redundancy, broker

[image]
There are two clients named **GC1** and **GC2** which communicates with each other through ActiveMQ using Topic "**GC1Alive**" & "**GC2Alive**". They just send the heartbeat with each other by using these topics.

**Purpose**

The purpose of communication between two GC's is that when **GC1** goes down then **GC2** should replace **GC1's** position in case of *Failover Scenario*.

Failover scenario is automatically handled by ActiveMQ on its own end with the following URL as given below:

```
URL = "failover://(tcp://<AMQ Broker Url 1>:61616,tcp://<AMQ Broker Url 2>:61616)?timeout=30000";
```

**Problem**

When **AMQ Broker 1** & **GC1** goes down, then the communication starts on **SideB**, between the **AMQ Broker 2** and **GC2**. Because when **GC2** didn't receive any beat from **GC1** after some time interval then **GC2** takeover **GC1** place and connect with **AMQ Broker 2** which is UP right now.

But when **AMQ Broker 1** & **GC1** goes UP again , **GC1** automatically sends beat to **AMQ Broker 1** which already defines in URL failover scenario. 
So now **GC1** send heartbeat to **AMQ Broker 1** and **GC2** send Heartbeat to **AMQ Broker 2**. 
So **GC1** and **GC2** are not redundant after the above use-case.

How can I make them redundant? Means when **GC1** and **AMQ Broker** Up again then How **GC1** check the heartbeat of **GC2** that is it alive or dead?

Is there any other design available which helps in making cluster between **GC1** and **GC2**?

Any help would be appreciated.